# Grouping JSON Objects

Tags: jquery, json

I am having difficulties grouping together JSON objects in an array. Essentially, I am creating a new blank array(A), iterating through an existing JSON array(B), checking if A contains an object where a property already exists in B, and if not then it creates a new object and pushes it to A.

This is what I'm attempting:

```
var grouped_requests = groupByProperty(campaign_requests, "send_date");
function groupByProperty(data, property) {
  var result = [];
  $.each(data, function(index, item) {
    var group;
    if ($.inArray(item[property], result)==-1) {
      // create a new group
      group = new Object();

      // set the group's properties
      group.deadline    = item.deadline;
      group.send_date   = item.send_date;
      group.description = item.description
      group.action = $('<button />', {
        class: "btn btn-primary",
        text: "Preview"
      }).attr('data-toggle', 'modal').attr('data-target', '#modal_request').attr('data-ids', data.map(function(m) {if (m.property = item.property) {return m}}).join(';')).prop('outerHTML');
     result.push(group);
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

Where I'm running into issues is two-fold. First, the $.inArray does not accurately check if A contains an object where the property in the parameter exists in B. Second, the data.map for the data-ids is returning blank values; e.g. if there are two identical properties it returns `;`.

**UPDATE**

Here is some sample data that I'm receiving:

```
[{
    "campaign_queue_id": "1",
    "email_id": "98",
    "subject": "Test1",
    "body": "Test1",
    "deadline": "June 17th,2018",
    "send_date": "June 17th, 2018",
    "description": "Customer"
}, {
    "campaign_queue_id": "2",
    "email_id": "22",
    "subject": "Test2",
    "body": "Test2",
    "deadline": "June 17th,2018",
    "send_date": "June 17th, 2018",
    "description": "Customer"
}, {
    "campaign_queue_id": "3",
    "email_id": "77",
    "subject": "Test3",
    "body": "Test3",
    "deadline": "June 20th,2018",
    "send_date": "June 25th, 2018",
    "description": "Center of Influence"
}, {
    "campaign_queue_id": "4",
    "email_id": "5",
    "subject": "Test4",
    "body": "Test4",
    "deadline": "June 20th,2018",
    "send_date": "June 25th, 2018",
    "description": "Center of Influence"
}]
```

And this is how I'm wanting to "group" the JSON data:

```
[{
  "deadline": "June 17th,2018",
  "send_date": "June 17th,2018",
  "description": "Customer",
  "action": "<button class=\"btn btn-primary\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#modal_request\" data-ids=\"1;2\">Preview</button>"
},
{
  "deadline": "June 20th,2018",
  "send_date": "June 25th,2018",
  "description": "Customer",
  "action": "<button class=\"btn btn-primary\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#modal_request\" data-ids=\"3;4\">Preview</button>"
}]
```

Comment: Post a sample `campaign_requests` format and the expected output.

Comment: create demo in fiddle

Comment: @Eddie - I've updated the post to include sample data and then how I'd expect the new output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve what I was trying to do by using the following code:

```
var send_dates = $.unique($.map(data, function(campaign) {
  return campaign.send_date;
}));

var campaigns = [];
$.each(send_dates, function(key, value) {
  var groups = $.grep(data, function(campaign) {
    return campaign.send_date === value;
  });
  var ids = $.map(groups, function(campaign) {
    return campaign.campaign_queue_id;
  });
  // create a new group
  var group = new Object();

  // set the group's properties
  group.deadline    = groups[0].deadline;
  group.send_date   = groups[0].send_date;
  group.description = groups[0].description;
  group.action = $('<button />', {
    class: 'btn btn-primary',
    text: 'Preview'
  }).attr('data-toggle', 'modal').attr('data-target', '#modal_request').attr('data-ids', ids.join(';')).prop('outerHTML');

  // add the group to the array
  campaigns.push(group);
});
```

However, I'm open to suggestions if there is a more efficient method.